# Problema com preloader na web

Tags: actionscript-3

Desenvolvi um projeto em que preciso exibir ao usuário que o arquivo em si está sendo carregado. O projeto possui duas cenas: Na primeira cena criei um `preloader` com o código:

```js
stop();

this.loaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, carregando);
this.loaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, carregou);

function carregando(e:ProgressEvent):void {
    preloader_txt.text = "CARREGANDO: "+int((this.stage.loaderInfo.bytesLoaded/this.stage.loaderInfo.bytesTotal)*100)+"%";  
}

function carregou(e:Event):void {
    play();
}
```

Na segunda cena está todo o conteúdo do meu arquivo `SWF`.

Configurei para que todas as minhas classes fossem importadas no Frame 2 da minha aplicação, sendo assim, o frame 1 seria responsável apenas por carregar o arquivo.

Quando eu faço o teste na máquina local, ocorre tudo com sucesso, vejo meu arquivo sendo carregado e a porcentagem é exibida na tela.

Porém quando eu subo para meu servidor na internet e o carrego, o preloader aparece apenas em 100%, ou seja, quando o flash está todo carregado.

Testei em browsers diferentes e ainda assim o problema ocorre.

Comment: Fica preso no zero e aparece 100% de uma vez?

Comment: Não! O preloader nem aparece quando o flash é chamado... Ele só aparece mesmo no 100%. É como se ele fosse inútil e não funcionasse, só pisca "100%" e começa a aparecer o conteúdo do SWF.

Comment: O `loaderInfo`já está no `stage`?

Comment: Não entendi muito bem a sua pergunta mas acredito que sim. Está importado no frame 1 e como eu falei, na máquina local o mesmo funciona corretamente.

Comment: Tem como colocar o código da primeira classe que ele executa (`main`)? Talvez ele só importe no stage depois que o swf está carregado.

Comment: Na verdade ele não possui uma classe main, embora eu já tenha testado incorporando uma com o mesmo código que eu postei acima na pergunta. Aconteceu a mesma coisa e o erro ainda continua.

Comment: Porque o que parece que está acontecendo é que ele está carregando primeiro TODO o `SWF`e o `MovieClip` só toca quando é carregado.

Comment: Você está usando o Flash Professional? Se sim, você desmarcou a opção de exportar tudo no primeiro frame?

Comment: @FelipeAvelar, aconselho você a ler a questão novamente, algumas de suas perguntas estão claras na questão. Enfim, não estamos chegando a lugar algum. Não possuo nenhum MovieClip no Stage, logo, que MovieClip está tocando?... O título da questão mostrava claramente que eu estava utilizando o Flash, mas você a editou... Por último, no terceiro parágrafo da pergunta eu citei que estou exportando tudo no segundo frame da aplicação. Obrigado mais uma vez por seu interesse em me ajudar! Fico no aguardo de possíveis soluções!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema! O problema estava no modo de compressão que o servidor efetuava no SWF, passando para o modo GZIP, quando na verdade ele deveria usar o DEFLATE.

A resposta eu consegui no SOEN neste link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22078076/preloader-does-not-work-online